# Constructing a new object in Rails that is part of an active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is just a simple question. I was trying to create a new object in Rails by passing in parameters to the constructor. However, when I execute the code, I get

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: awards.user_id: SELECT "awards".* FROM "awards"  WHERE "awards"."user_id" = 1
```

which means the object isn't being constructed properly. Should I be using *create* instead of *new*? That isn't working either.

```
def refresh_awards(user)

new_awards = []

if (user.karma < 40 ) #test award

    a = Award.new(:name => "Nobody Award", :description => "From Jonathan", :category => "Community", :value => 1337, :level => 0, :handle => "nobody_award")
    user.awards.append(a)
    new_awards.append(a)

end

new_awards.each do |a|

    flash[:notice] = "You received the " + a.name + "!"

end

end
```

Comment: user.awards will try to load the user's awards, do you have the relationship set up correctly, and has the migration been run?

Comment: ah, you're right, user.awards isn't properly set up. do you know the documentation i can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you add `has_many :awards` to the `User` model? Have you added `belongs_to :user` to the `Award` model? Have you added the column `user_id` to the `Award` model (using a migration)? You'll need to do these three things to be able to use the `user.awards` method you're using.  Read the [Rails Guide on Associations](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html&ei=RWjmT9mME429iAertYRZ&usg=AFQjCNEiaqyRhMemV_2s_ZqwjTaYdA42bQ&sig2=1XnJTum0xuhqfgrEgwu2_A) for more detail.

Also, `append` isn't a Ruby method - the closest method would be `<<`. You would use it like this:

```
a = Award.new(:name => "Nobody Award", :description => "From Jonathan", :category => "Community", :value => 1337, :level => 0, :handle => "nobody_award")
user.awards << a
```

But you could neaten this into one line of code using the `create` method:

```
a = user.awards.create(:name => "Nobody Award", :description => "From Jonathan", :category => "Community", :value => 1337, :level => 0, :handle => "nobody_award")
```

EDIT: To create the `user_id` column in the `Award` model, run the following code from terminal (while in your app's directory):

```
rails generate migration AddUserIdToAward user_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: thanks. i had already looked up the docs just now but this is the gist of what i added

Comment: Is user.awards.append(a) a valid statement?  I've never seen it (append) before and tried finding it in the docs and couldn't.

Comment: Can't find `append` anywhere - shouldn't have assumed it was valid! Looks like `<<` is the closest to `append` in Ruby. Will edit the answer.